# How to use method parameter as parameter in another method?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Class1(object):
   def __init__(self, parameter1):
        # action with parameter

   def method1(self, parameter1):
        # method actions
```

So what I want to happen is that I am able to make a `Class1` object without having loaded the `parameter1` yet and then when that has happened, I use `method1` to set `parameter1` and run actions with `method1` as `__init__` will use the results of `method1`. This is a python tutorial practice exam by the way so it has to be done this way.

EDIT:

```
>>>object1 = Class1()
>>>object1.method1(parameter1)
```

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you mean with *“without having loaded the parameter yet”*? You don’t *load* parameters. Either you pass them, or you don’t. Do you want to be able to create the object without specifying the parameter and then later finish the initialization using the method?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. So that is what I want to be able to do in the edit.

Comment: You could pass `None` as `parameter1` and then reset it later, but as it stands you cannot initialise a `Class1` object without passing *something* for that parameter.

Comment: How do I reset it later?

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow a later initialization, you want to move all your actual initialization stuff into the method and make the parameter to the `__init__` optional. Then, if the parameter is specified, you can call the method or not.

```
class SomeClass (object):
   def __init__ (self, param = None):
        # do some general initialization, like initializing instance members
        self.foo = 'bar'

        # if the parameter is specified, call the init method
        if param is not None:
            self.init(param)

   def init (self, param):
        # do initialization stuff
```

Then, both of the following ways to create the object are equivalent:

```
x = SomeClass('param value')

y = SomeClass()
y.init('param value')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to be able to assign a value for the attribute at the method level and not in the initialization of the Class, I would suggest the following implementation:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, parameter=None):
        self.parameter=parameter

    def method(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter
```

You can check that the attribute is certainly assigned through the method:

```
>>> c = Class1()
>>> c.method('whatever')
>>> print(c.parameter)
whatever
```

BTW in Python3 you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object` anymore, since already "[all classes inherit from object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)".